# fcpdf give height to cell as per text

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using FPDF and making table in it using FancyTable example from here http://www.fpdf.org/. Following, I am showing one glimpse of code.

```
$start_x   = $this->GetX(); //initial x (start of column position)
$current_y = $this->GetY();
$current_x = $this->GetX();
$cell_height = 7;

$this->MultiCell($width,$cell_height,$data,0,'L',$fill);
$current_x+=$width;  //calculate position for next cell
$this->SetXY($current_x, $current_y);
```

Output of this is following, You can see one cell data is going outside cell. I have highlighted one cell data that is going outside from cell.

[image]

If I increase the height of cell then it seems it increase the line height and not cell height. Following is sample code.

```
$cell_height = 25;
$this->MultiCell($width,$cell_height,$data,0,'L',$fill);
```

and output looks like following.

[image]

Comment: If you want to make a table with MultiCells, the script [Table with MultiCells](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=3) can help.

Comment: @Olivier Yes It solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: In my code, there was background color in the heading row but with the latest code, SetFillColor is not giving background, here you can see https://prnt.sc/1qs84my

Comment: To get a background color, change the call to `Rect()` like this: `$this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h,'DF');`.